# ECONNREFUSED using nightwatch-accessibility library

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm trying to use the [nightwatch-accessibility](https://github.com/ahmadnassri/nightwatch-accessibility) library, but keep getting error

```
    POST  /session/b4e18278544c74b9213c030b8119ee7e/timeouts/async_script - ECONNREFUSED
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9515
 Error while running .setTimeoutsAsyncScript() protocol action: An unknown error has occurred.

    POST  /session/b4e18278544c74b9213c030b8119ee7e/execute_async - ECONNREFUSED
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9515
 Error while running .executeScriptAsync() protocol action: An unknown error has occurred.
```

Normal tests work fine. As far as I can tell I am following the example correctly. The test assertions work correctly it just appears at the end of the test run.

**nightwatch.json**

```
{
    "src_folders": ["test"],
    "page_objects_path": "page-objects",
    "globals_path": "./globals.js",
    "custom_commands_path": ["./node_modules/nightwatch-accessibility/commands"],
    "custom_assertions_path": ["./node_modules/nightwatch-accessibility/assertions"],
    "end_session_on_fail": false,
    "skip_testcases_on_fail": false,

    "selenium": {
        "start_process": false
    },

    "webdriver": {
        "start_process": true,
        "server_path": "node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe",
        "port": 9515
    },

    "test_settings": {
        "default": {
            "webdriver.port": 9515,
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "chrome"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**globals.js**

```
const chromedriver = require('chromedriver');

module.exports = {
    before: function (done) {
        chromedriver.start();
        done();
    },

    after: function (done) {
        chromedriver.stop();
        done();
    }
};
```

**First test**

```
module.exports = {
    '@tags': ['accessibility'],
    'First test': function (browser) {
        browser
            .url(`http://www.google.com`)
            .pause(3000)
            .initAccessibility()
            .assert.accessibility('html', {
                verbose: true
            })

            .end()
    }
}
```

Executing by typing **nightwatch** from the terminal like I would other tests. Any ideas and is this the best accessibility assertion library for NightwatchJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [nightwatch-axe-verbose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nightwatch-axe-verbose) instead. Usage details included on this [web accessibility testing using nightwatch](https://www.davidmello.com/accessibility-testing-with-nightwatchjs/) blog post.